# How do I set a default window manager for XDM?

Tags: linux, x11

I would like to setup XDM so that all users are logged into the Blackbox window manager by default (without adding a `.xsession` file to each home directory). Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

System-wide resources are defined in `/etc/X11/Xresources/`, all you have to do is add a `xsession` file in that path.

Make sure the file is world-readable but not world-writable.

Comment: That didn't work for me.